# How to change the dependency manager of the installed JHipster generator and a JHipster project?

Tags: npm, jhipster, yeoman, dependency-management, yarnpkg

I installed JHipster generator using Yarn:

> yarn global add generator-jhipster

Now I have two concerns:

1- What if I change my mind and want to generate new JHipster projects managed by "npm" when I use the yeoman command?

I mean:

> yo jhipster

Should I install JHipster generator again, using "npm" this time?

I mean:

> npm install -g generator-jhipster

2-How should I switch from "yarn" to "npm" on a project which is already using "yarn" as the dependency/package manager?

Answer (score 5):

1. Uninstall from yarn first, then install using npm and no need to use `yo jhipster`, just use `jhipster`
2. Edit `.yo-rc.json` file and change value of clientPackageManager property to "npm", delete `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`, re-generate with `jhipster --with-entities`

Comment: It worked for me. This is reported as a "manual update" task, for a jhipster project, as stated in this page: https://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/
Maybe it could be useful for other changes as welll.